# How to use XML Parser and get element by tagName when tag contains embedded element inside?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xml-parsing

I'm using XMLParser to get data from a tag.

This tag is like this :

```
<tagName elem="XXX"></tagName>
```

I want to get : `XXX`

According to documentation, I'm doing like :

```
    parseMyXML = new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc = parseMyXML.parseFromString(contentXML,"text/xml");

    var code_XXX = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I have an error : `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined`

What I need is to go into `tagName` and to get the contain of `elem`

Comment: Try changing the mime type to "application/xml"

Comment: @Eytibi — Why? What difference would that make?

Comment: Nevermind. It was just a guess as in documentations you always find "aplication/xml".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an **attribute** not a child node.

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagName")[0].getAttribute("elem");
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery you can do something like this.

```
    var $xml = $.parseXML(xml),
       value = $xml.find('tagName').text();
```

if you're using plain JS  you should parse xml like this.

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
  // code for modern browsers
  parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
} else {
  // code for old IE browsers
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
}
```

Comment: They aren't using jQuery, and the content they are trying to read isn't the text inside the element.

Comment: @Quentin yes but I am suggesting the way, if he wants i can give the plain example. and if he is not want the text he can remove that part.

Comment: The question tells you what the OP wants. It isn't what you explained how to get. You need to answer the actual question.

Comment: Let him decide, what he wants, if he needs more explanation, he will ask. he can ask you better as he is working on the issue.

Comment: "Let him decide, what he wants" — They did. They told us what they want in the question. They want the value XXX which is the value of the elem **attribute**. It is not the text inside the element. There isn't any text inside the element.